# Select where not equal to multiple values of keys of associative array

Tags: php, mysql, select, associative-array

I had made three tables.

**Table1=users**.And the column names are **userid** (auto_increment) and **username**.
**Table2=hobbies**. column names are **hobbyid** (auto_increment) and **hobbyname**.
**Table3=users_hobbies**. column names are FK_userid and FK_hobbyid.

Now **hobbyname** has **cricket,football,volleyball**.
During sign-up user **selects only cricket and football** and I store it in **$_SESSION['hobby_id']** associative array.

But in profile he/she wants to add some more hobbies.

So I want to **display list of hobbies which are not equal** to $_SESSION['hobby_id'].

This , ofcourse didn't work:

```
foreach($_SESSION['hobby_id'] as $k=>$v)
{

  $query="select hobbyid,hobbyname from hobbies where hobbyid!= $v";
}  
Output was football,volleyball and cricket,volleyball....but i wanted only volleyball
```

So i want that

```
$query="select hobbyid,hobbyname from hobbies where hobbyid!=(multiple values of session hobby id)";
```

What code will I have to enter to get **desired result(only volleyball)**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `foreach`loop and use `NOT IN` comparision in MySQL:

```
$query="
    SELECT hobbyid,hobbyname
    FROM hobbies
    WHERE hobbyid NOT IN (" . implode(',', $_SESSION['hobby_id']) . ")
";
```

Comment: worked like a charm!.. there was problem when the $_SESSION['hobby_id'] was empty but i solved it by using simple if(empty($_SESSION['hobby_id']))......  **thanks**

Comment: Sure you have to check if variable is not empty, I give you only the final query. But you have to ensure, that `$_SESSION['hobby_id']` contains only numeric values (in fact of SQL injection)